# IPN delay and SAAS application

Tags: paypal, delay, paypal-ipn, saas

I have a SAAS web application that works through a subscription fee. If the subscription is valid everything works fine, otherwise the app goes in read-only mode until the customer renew the subscription. I've developed the payment flow with the PayPal API.

The problem is that PayPal Documentation says this:

```
"Although PayPal usually processes IPN messages immediately, IPN is not synchronized with actions on your website. Internet connectivity is not always 100% reliable and IPN messages can be lost or delayed. The IPN service automatically resends messages until the listener acknowledges them. The service resends messages for up to 4 days.
Because IPN is not a real-time service, your checkout flow should not wait for the IPN message before it is allowed to complete. If the checkout flow is dependent on receiving an IPN message, processing can be delayed by system load or other reasons. You should configure your checkout flow to handle a possible delay."
```

Unfortunately this is exactly my case: when customers renew the subscription I need to immediately activate the app so I placed all the logic right in the "notify callback" where I have to create the order, send a confirmation email, update some session variables... but I if there's a delay from PayPal IPN this is a problem!
In these days I did some test in Sandbox mode and in several cases I got an answer from IPN even 4 hours after the successful payment! This is unacceptable for my app!

Finally the question: what's the best solution for my case? It makes sense to move the application activation from "notify callback" to "success callback"? There may be problems?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use IPN for this; it's a poor fit & not designed to be inserted into synchronous user experience flows. It works fine as a way to initiate offline fulfillment, but can delay your customers if they are actively waiting for access.

You don't specify which PayPal product you are using, but each product should provide a way to immediately give you feedback that the payment has been completed. For example with Express Checkout or any API-based payment you can take action (activate/re-activate a subscription) when you receive the successful API response (the DoEC API in the case of Express Checkout).

With web-only/non-API products you can take action when the customer redirects to your return_url, using PDT to securely get information about the transaction if you need that (it can include an IPN-style key that you post back to PayPal to verify, exactly as you do with an IPN).

If you are concerned about the edge cases of someone closing their browser before it can redirect to you, or some other sort of dropped connection or programming error, you can *also* check & activate/fulfill upon receipt of an IPN to catch any fallout. So all customers that complete a normal payment flow are activated immediately; if they do something wonky (or your code breaks, or whatever) then the activation still happens, albeit potentially delayed by a few seconds or minutes.

Comment: I'm using the Express checkout method. Today I moved the activation logic in the success callback and everything works fine as before without the IPN annoying delay. Your last advice is very interesting! Thank you!